# Reset form on event listener already on form

Tags: javascript, forms, addeventlistener, reset, dom-events

I'd like to add a form reset on a form.  I know this is simple enough by doing form.reset().

However, I already have an event listener, on the same form. So adding reset() into for function does not work.

Here's my form event listener, to do something on submit. How do I get my form to reset first, before doing anything, in the same function/event listener?

```
  searchForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = domEvents.getSearchTerm();
    domEvents.displaySearchTerm(searchTerm);

    unsplashService.getImages(searchTerm)
      .then((response) => {
        const res = JSON.parse(response.response);
        const imageURLs = res.results.map(images => images.urls.small);

        if (imageURLs.length > 0) {
          domEvents.displayImages(imageURLs);
        } else {
          errorPlaceholder.innerHTML = 'No results. Search again!';
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error) {
          domEvents.showNetworkError();
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: did not understand this `I add a form reset on this event listener`. Reset and submit are two different ones. Not getting what you are trying to say..

Comment: Essentially, there's my form to do something on submit.  How do I get my form to reset first, before doing anything, in the same function/event listener?

Comment: If you reset the form, the you would loose all the data. So inside the `submit` listener, first collect all the data you need from the form and its elements, then, do a `form.reset` the would work.

Comment: that doesn't work, as the first thing i want to do, after e.prevent default, is reset the form...